# C# FlowLayoutPanel custom border not properly resizeable

Tags: c#, border, flowlayoutpanel

I'd like to create a FlowLayoutPanel with a black border.
For this I've used the Paint-Method with following code:

```
private void flowLayoutPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle, Color.Black, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
}
```

My problem is, when I'm resizing the form, therefore the FlowLayoutPanel, the black border isn't properly displayed.
[Screenshot of the border.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIV3w.png)

Just in case: I've added `DoubleBuffered = true;` to the main function.

Is there any possible way to fix this issue?

Comment: ClipRectangle is not what you want.  Use the control's ClientRectangle.  You also have to clear the canvas, too: `e.Graphics.Clear(flowLayoutPanel.BackColor);`  It's not clear if this is inherited or not, but you need to add ResizeRedraw = true in the control's constructor, or just call `flowLayoutPanel.Invalidate();` in the control's Resize event.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Worked for me, but I have to use ClipRectangle because the bottom and the right border is missing when I'm using ClientRectangle.

Comment: Did you use the ClientRectangle of the FlowLayoutPanel?

Comment: Well, _insert Facepalm_ I did not. But what's the difference between ClientRectangle or ClipRectangle, and what are the advantages of both? Because both woked properly.

Comment: Differences can be minor or a big "gotcha".  ClipRectangle is really the only part of the control that is getting "dirty".  It's been working for you because chances are, the entire ClientRectangle is getting invalidated.